# My Unknown Numbers of Input Code Duplicates the Last Input

Tags: c, input, while-loop

I'm working on one of my C assignments. I have a little problem with taking unknown numbers of input. This is my code:

```
    while ((a = getchar()) != EOF){
        ungetc(a,stdin);
        scanf(" %c %d %d %d",&a,&b,&c,&d);
        arr1[3*i] = b;
        arr1[3*i+1] = c;
        arr1[3*i+2] = d;
        i++;
```

(I have done all the declaretions befor this)

What i'm trying to do this here is I take inputs and stroe them in three arrays. My input is:

X 10 18 3

r -3 2 1

Y 0 -2 -1

After i write these in terminal, i have to push the buttons ctrl+d twice. And then when i try to check arr1, its like {10, 18, 3, -3 ,2 ,1 ,0 ,-2 ,-1 ,0 ,-2 ,-1} The last input is duplicated and i don't know the reason..

!!! The main thing is that I don't that how many inputs i will take. !!!

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `while (scanf(" %c%d%d%d",&a,&b,&c,&d) == 4)` is the normal way to write the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After each scanf, the file pointer is left on the trailing newline of input.  After the last line of input is scanned and values are assigned to b, c, and d, the `getchar` in the while loop reads the final newline.  Then scanf reads no values so b, c, and d are unchanged.  The values that were left from the previous loop are assigned to the array, i is incremented, and then getchar returns EOF and the loop breaks.  Always check the value returned by scanf.  In other words, this problem evaporates if you use the usual idiom

```
while(scanf(" %c%d%d%d",&a,&b,&c,&d) == 4) { ...
```

Also, in this case, the error would have been noticed more readily if you weren't copying the data unnecessarily to the temporary variables b, c, and d, but just did:

```
while( scanf(" %c%d%d%d", &a, arr + 3*i, arr + 3*i +1, arr + 3*i + 2) == 4
```

which would be written a lot more cleanly as:

```
int *base = arr;
while( scanf(" %c%d%d%d", &a, base, base + 1, base + 2) == 4 ) {
    base += 3; ...
```

Note that in all of these, `a` must really be declared as a char, but to assign `a` from `getchar` requires that `a` be an `int`, and that should be a clue that trying to use `getchar/ungetc` is a mistake.

To summarize, on all but the first line of input, `getchar` is reading '\n', `ungetc` pushes that newline back to the buffer, and then `scanf` skips over it because of the leading whitespace in the format string.

Answer (score 0):

regarding:

```
while ((a = getchar()) != EOF){
    ungetc(a,stdin);
    scanf(" %c %d %d %d",&a,&b,&c,&d);
    arr1[3*i] = b;
    arr1[3*i+1] = c;
    arr1[3*i+2] = d;
    i++;
```

Suggest using the returned value from `scanf()`, similar to:

```
int i = 0;
while ( scanf(" %c %d %d %d",&a,&b,&c,&d) == 4 )
{
    arr1[3*i] = b;
    arr1[3*i+1] = c;
    arr1[3*i+2] = d;
    i++;
}
```